# Problem with tree render

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm newbie and tried to do a tree in blender, basing on YT tutorials. Unfortunately, it's looks like most of leaves disappear, when i render it, while the rest, are completely dark. In object-mode view, all leaves are normally visible. What is the cause?

[image: my tree]
[image: texture nodes]
[image: material preview]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the 3d view and the eventual particle system settings? Could you also add the link to the tutorials you mentioned or describe the workflow you followed? (there are many ways to build a tree)

Comment: I based on this: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fXQhILVl9U). Here is screenshot [3Dview](http://i.imgur.com/oPWIhPF.png). I didn't do anything with particles systems.

When I turn on "texture view" in Object mode all leaves go dark, despite that in material preview, texture is green.

Comment: It could be that your leaves aren't unwrapped, they won't use texture and material settings in that case. Check if [unwrapping](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping.html) was done and examine how does UV map look like.